# I want to insert "Not Provided" when null

Tags: sql

I want to insert 'not provided' in the column that gets a users contact info. I do not have the user required to give contact information but when I am pulling the data back for reporting purposes I want the report to show 'not provided' instead of being left blank since the value will be null.

How do I write the insert query to make this possible?

Comment: You may wish to leave data in the table as is (null) and `select .. coalesce(col, 'not provided') col ..` to replace null with the desired text for reporting purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE [table]
SET [column]= 'Not Provided'
WHERE [column] IS NULL;
```

Where table = your table name
And column = your column name